# Use Vector Assembler and extracting "features" as org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark

I have wanted to use the Gaussian Mixture Model in Spark 1.5.1 which uses the linalg.mllib.vector rdd .

This is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.GaussianMixture
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.GaussianMixtureModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions
dummy = dummy.na.drop
var colnames= dummy.columns
var df = dummy

for(x<-colnames)
{ 
    if (dummy.select(x).dtypes(0)._2.equals("StringType") || dummy.select(x).dtypes(0)._2.equals("LongType"))
    { df = df.drop(x)}

}

var colnames = df.columns
var assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(colnames).setOutputCol("features")
var output = assembler.transform(df)
var temp = output.select("features")
```

The problem is i am not able to change the feature column into  `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` rdd

Anyone has an idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.0**

Either map:

```
temp.rdd.map(_.getAs[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]("features"))
```

or use `as`:

```
temp
  .select("features")
  .as[Tuple1[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector]]
  .rdd.map(_._1)
```

**Spark < 2.0**

Just `map` over `RDD[Row]` and extract the field:

```
temp.rdd.map(_.getAs[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]("features"))
```

Comment: You sir, are a godsend! Why spark decides to use 'Any' as the default type instead of the df's content is beyond me.

Comment: @Havnar Mostly because `DataFrame` is an inherently dynamic structure. While extensions like `frameless` are possible, they don't provide experience, that users used to data frames expect. There are also not portable to Java and impractical with wide datasets and ad hoc analytics.